# You don’t have permission to view or edit anything - only super users is able to do everything

Tags: django

I have a model registered in Django admin. Then I created two users superuser and a normal user. This normal user was given the **staff=True**, **read** and **change** rights for **News** model by the superuser. However, when i log in with this new user it is giving me `You don’t have permission to view or edit anything.`

```
@admin.register(News)
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     pass
```

What needs to be done? I am using Django 3.2

Comment: What do you do that gives this error? What is the exact error? Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: I have edited it, though it is not an error that is coming out.

Comment: When you say "I log in", do you mean you got to `http://localhost:8000/admin` and it gives you a dialaog box?

Comment: Will you login as the super user then navigate to view the permissions of the normal user? Grab a screenshot and post it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The admin console is only useable by superuser or "staff" user. You need to set one or both of these fields on the user to `True`.

Comment: staff is set to true